# Simple preloader that loads all resources and caches them before showing site and running animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple preloader that will request and preload all resources until everything is cached. Then the website should fade-in. The issue what I am having is that Im not sure if my code below is ok as im still a novice. Also what I cant manage to achieve is stop any css3 animation from firing before the preloader finishes. Forexample, I have alot of fade in and slide in effects when the websites is loaded. When the preloader runs it also somehow fires my animations in the background...hence when my site is loaded no animation is shown.

So I need to be able to

1) Preload all resources and cache them before the site is shown (meanwhile it shows a small gif)

2) When loading it should prevent animations from firing. When it is done the site shows and then starts to trigger all css3 animations. The animations are only fired once by the way which is why im concerned.

Here a JsFiddle. I hope that is ok as I am still new to this website and dont use it very often other than notepad ++ or dreamweaver:

http://jsfiddle.net/5w2JU/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
            $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
            $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
            $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
        })
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery .addclass() if loading is complete.